# reject HostKey PHPStorm

Tags: phpstorm, sftp

I am using PHPStorm, V8. Anytime I attempt to create a remote host connection (SFTP), it returns the following error: reject HostKey: sitename

This happens to any site. I have scoured the webs and cannot find what the issue is, and how to fix it.

Is there anybody out there that has dealt with this problem?

Thanks,
Brad

[Image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuBfZ.png)

Comment: Maybe you need to rewrite/resync your key? http://askubuntu.com/questions/45679/ssh-connection-problem-with-host-key-verification-failed-error

Comment: I am not sure what that means. Can you point me in the right direction to read up on something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured out a workaround, if this plagues anybody else.

If you start a new SSH session (Tools | Start SSH Session), select Edit Credential, and put in your information it will create the SSH key for that connection. Once you do this, you should be able to use SFTP for that connection.

It's not perfect, but it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You should accept your own answer btw